# Transfer application files from Linux to iOS device?

Tags: ios

I want to know if there is any way I could transfer application files(like pdfs to Adobe Reader, videos to Infuse, epubs to Marvin) from my Linux machine to my iPad, preferably wirelessly. I am running Ubuntu on my PC and iOS 9.3.1 on my iPad. I used to able to access and transfer application files between my iPad and Linux till iOS 7(if I remember correctly) via USB cable, but that just stopped working after iOS 8. Is there any way to bring that back or is there a way to do this wirelessly?

Answer (score 4):

You can transfer files to and from your iOS device using an app called FileApp:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fileapp-documents-files-reader/id297804694

FileApp has a "share files over wifi" feature with clear instructions on how to transfer files.  To upload files to your device, you can use FileApp's simple web interface.  Use an FTP client like Filezilla (available in the Ubuntu software center) to copy files from your iOS device to your computer.

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments below, once the file is loaded in FileApp, you can copy it to any app that is registered to handle that filetype through the actions menu. For example, video and audio files of most types (even those not normally supported on iOS) can be copied to [VLC for Mobile](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vlc-for-mobile/id650377962) for playback. After you have copied the file to the destination app, you can delete the original from FileApp to free up storage space.

Comment: Been there, done that. It works but be aware that Apple segregates app data each in its sandbox. As a result, files you send to FileApp will *only* be visible to FileApp No Adobe Reader, Infuse, Marvin. Apart from that, FileApp allows you to do most of what you expect: browse files, view images, most videos, PDF, etc. So in practice should suit your use case.

Comment: You can transfer files from FileApp to other apps.  For example, I load movie files onto FileApp and transfer them to VLC for iOS to watch them (I don't like certain things about FileApp's builtin movie playback).  I have not tried it, but I imagine you could do the same with at least some of the apps you mention.

Comment: **Thanks for notifying.**  Still, it confirms Apple segregates app data each in its sandbox.  (1) Each file has to be explicitly "transferred" using "Actions..." menu. (2) Only recipient apps specially registered to iOS for the specific type can be recipient (VLC if video, iBooks if PDF).  (3) Files "transferred" this way are indeed physically copied (duplicated) on iOS filesystem, which can be a no-go for big files (e.g. videos).  So, this works for a handful of files but is far from a real filesystem as computers have had for decades.

Comment: I noticed a race condition occurring if you switch to the recipient app before transfer is completed.  VLC complains file is not found, showing full path. **All in all, the scheme is: transfer once from Linux to FileApp and use there, or in few cases, transfer again from FileApp to actual app.**

Answer (score 1):

Use dropbox, google drive, and the like. These app even allows two-way transfering. For example, you may want to transfer some photos to your computer sometimes.

Comment: I would not use dropbox, Google Drive and the like. Those  assume an Internet connection that sends all your data to the cloud and back. Hope you're not transferring heavy files.